# Using function TOLOWER in R

Tags: r

I have a table in program R. How to convert names of variables (which at the same time are the names of columns) to lowercase with the help of fubction TOLOWER? [image]

Comment: You can do `names(df) = tolower(names(df))`

Comment: I always use `janitor::clean_names`. It also handles other strange colnames..